# File share artifacts are not removed on pipeline deletion (Azure DevOps Server 2022)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2022

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 on-premises.

We have pipelines publishing build artifacts to a file share with "Publish build artifacts v1" task.

When we delete such a pipeline, it's artifacts remain in the file share, taking up disk space.

Additional info:

- The automatic retention is working as expected and the artifacts are removed from the file share according to the rules.
- When we delete a single run manually (after removing all retention leases), the artifacts are deleted immediately.
- When we remove retention leases from runs of a pipeline and then delete the pipeline - the artifacts are not removed.
- We tried to wait several days to see whether the artifacts are removed at some later stage, but the artifacts remain in the file share and are not deleted.

The pipeline deletion dialog has a note "Deletion includes all builds and associated artifacts". According to this, I would expect all artifacts to be deleted on pipeline deletion.

What may be the issue?
Why the artifacts are not being removed on pipeline deletion (regardless of the retention status)?

Comment: I don't think it's an issue at all, it's always behaved this way.

Comment: @DanielMann maybe, but the pipeline deletion is very poorly documented - that's all I found in Microsoft docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser#how-can-i-delete-a-pipeline. I am new to this and this behavior is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> When we remove retention leases from runs of a pipeline and then delete the pipeline - the artifacts are not removed.

This is because the build pipeline is NOT permanently deleted actually. You can still find it in the `Deleted Pipelines` and restore it.

[image]

If you want to completely delete the build, you can use retention policy. Or you can delete every build runs then delete the build, so that every artifact will be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I still suspect issues since pipelines that were already permanently removed (not appear as deleted) have left artifacts behind. I will monitor the pipelines I see currently in deleted list and update later.

Comment: Hi @ika, may i know if there's any update? Does the artifact still exist even the pipeline permantently removed?

Comment: Yes, I have monitored several deleted pipelines and the artifacts remain in the drop folder even after the pipelines were permanently deleted.